# Как сделать Load/Save Json файл в таблицу (QTableView)?

Tags: c++, json, qt

Есть таблица QTableView 5 строчек и 2 столбца.

Название шапки Trip name и Trip days.
(прошу не писать там вот я такой и сякой и т.п. Я знаю что плохо просить без какой-то реализации.)

Как создать таблицу и руками заполнить ее знаю.

Но все рано объясните пожалуйста. Я прошу помочь так сдать лабу надо и в инете норм информации не нашел. Прошу комьюнити помочь с этим.)

Задание лабораторной работы:

> В приложении пусть будет меню File с пунктами меню Load… и Save…, с
>   помощью которых можно будет загрузить и сохранить файлы
>   соответственно. Пусть используются диалоги открытия и сохранения для
>   выбора целевого файла. Пусть данные хранятся в файле в формате JSON.
>   Отделите логику по загрузке/сохранению данных в файл в отдельный
>   класс.

Answer (score 2):

[Реализация проекта на Qt5](https://github.com/gil9red/table_save_load_as_json). Все, что ниже уже есть в репозитории проекта.

Так как автор темы не указал версию `Qt`, то я выбрал ту, на которой мне удобнее было бы написать. `Json` в `Qt4` по умолчанию нет, но можно [собрать и присоединить к проекту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147952/) стороннюю библиотеку [QJson](http://qjson.sourceforge.net/), поддерживающую `Qt`.

Также, выбор модели для таблицы был на мой выбор.

Ниже я приведу код класса окна и класса для сохранения / загрузки из Json.

---

**Класс окна:**

h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenu>
#include <QMenuBar>
#include <QAction>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void load();
    void save();

private:
    QTableView view;
    QStandardItemModel model;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "modelstorage.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QMenu* fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
    fileMenu->addAction("Load", this, SLOT(load()));
    fileMenu->addAction("Save", this, SLOT(save()));

    QStringList headers = QStringList() << "Trip name" << "Trip days";
    model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
    model.setColumnCount(headers.size());

    const int rowCount = 5;

    for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++) {
        QList <QStandardItem *> rowItems;

        for (int column = 0; column < model.columnCount(); column++) {
            QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(QString("%1_%2x%3").arg(headers[column]).arg(row).arg(column));
            rowItems.append(item);
        }

        model.appendRow(rowItems);
    }

    view.setModel(&model);

    setCentralWidget(&view);
}

void MainWindow::load()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this);
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    ModelStorage::load(fileName, model);
}
void MainWindow::save()
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this);
    if (fileName.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    ModelStorage::save(fileName, model);
}
```

---

**Класс для работы с Json:**

h:

```
#ifndef MODELSTORAGE_H
#define MODELSTORAGE_H

#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStandardItem>

#include <QFile>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QJsonArray>

class ModelStorage
{
public:
    static bool load(const QString& fileName, QStandardItemModel & model);
    static bool save(const QString& fileName, const QStandardItemModel& model);
};

#endif // MODELSTORAGE_H
```

cpp:

```
#include "modelstorage.h"


bool ModelStorage::load(const QString& fileName, QStandardItemModel& model) {
    QFile loadFile(fileName);
    if (!loadFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        qWarning("Couldn't open save file.");
        return false;
    }

    QByteArray saveData = loadFile.readAll();
    QJsonDocument loadDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(saveData);
    QJsonObject json = loadDoc.object();

    // Очистка модели
    while (model.rowCount() > 0) {
        model.invisibleRootItem()->removeRow(0);
    }

    const int rowCount = json["rowCount"].toInt();
    const int columnCount = json["columnCount"].toInt();
    QJsonArray data = json["data"].toArray();

    model.setRowCount(rowCount);
    model.setColumnCount(columnCount);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        QJsonArray row = data[i].toArray();

        for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
            model.setItem(i, j, new QStandardItem(row[j].toString()));
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool ModelStorage::save(const QString& fileName, const QStandardItemModel& model) {
    QFile saveFile(fileName);
    if (!saveFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
        qWarning("Couldn't open save file.");
        return false;
    }

    QJsonObject json;
    json["rowCount"] = model.rowCount();
    json["columnCount"] = model.columnCount();

    QJsonArray data;
    for (int i = 0; i < model.rowCount(); i++) {
        QJsonArray row;

        for (int j = 0; j < model.columnCount(); j++) {
            row.append(QJsonValue(model.item(i, j)->text()));
        }

        data.append(row);
    }
    json["data"] = data;

    QJsonDocument saveDoc(json);
    saveFile.write(saveDoc.toJson());

    return true;
}
```

---

**Скриншот окна и json, описывающий таблицу:**
[image: Скриншот окна и json, описывающий таблицу]

Порядок строк в массиве json не должен меняться при сохранении в json, но для уменьшения симптомов параноий можно передавать и номер строки таблицы :)